# How text of <a> tag can be obtained in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

```
<a itemprop="director" href="/name/nm0000116/" onclick="(new Image()).src='/rg/title-overview/director-1/images/b.gif?link=%2Fname%2Fnm0000116%2F';">
James Cameron
</a>
```

I want "James Cameron" as output, but unfortunately there is no function to get text like `getText()` etc. Please help me that how can I get it"

Answer (score 1):

There is `Text` property for that purpose:

```
IWebElement anchor = Driver.FindElementByTagName("a");
string innerText = anchor.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't locate the method FindElementByTagName(). If you have trouble with that too, maybe this can work.

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.Firefox());
IWebElement anchor = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
string text = anchor.Text;
```